# KO Component - Persist DOM elements within component binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm taking my first swing at designing a component with KO's 3.2 release.

Currently, I am trying to create a grid and really want to expose the relevant markup to the programmer for the head and body section of the resulting table element that will be generated by the component.

Here is an example of what I'm trying achieve in terms of **desired syntactical flavor**:

```
<pht-dataGrid params="{ model: dataGridModel, 
                        header: 'data-header', 
                        lineItem: 'data-line-item', 
                        itemContent: 'data-item-content' }">

                 <script type="text/html" id="data-header">
                    <th class="AlignLeft"><h3>Column 1</h3></th>
                    <th class="AlignLeft"><h3>Column 2</h3></th>
                </script>

                <script type="text/html" id="data-line-item">
                    <td><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></td>
                    <td>Some Type</td>
                </script>
</pht-datagrid>
```

The issue with this approach is that KO simply guts out the `pht-dataGrid` component when it initiates the rendering process.

**Question: Is there anyway to sidestep this behavior to achieve the effect I'm after?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported as you've described. You could move the script blocks outside of the component block.

```
<pht-dataGrid params="{ model: dataGridModel, 
                        header: 'data-header', 
                        lineItem: 'data-line-item', 
                        itemContent: 'data-item-content' }">
</pht-datagrid>

<script type="text/html" id="data-header">
    <th class="AlignLeft"><h3>Column 1</h3></th>
    <th class="AlignLeft"><h3>Column 2</h3></th>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="data-line-item">
    <td><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></td>
    <td>Some Type</td>
</script>
```

There are currently some open issues about possible ways to do this:

- [Request feature: runtime composition of ko 3.2 component](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1463)
- [Can I override component views with data-parts?](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1493)

Comment: Great answer even though the answer is that it's not supported. Love the issue links! Added my own comments that to hopefully bolster the cause! Thanks!